# Unable to connect Local MongoDB with Node js with Credential

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am facing issue to connect with Local mongoDB.

**Mongo Connection string:**

```
  const options = {
    'useMongoClient': true,

  };
  mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/DB?authSource=admin", options);
  mongoose.connection.on('error', error => {
    console.log(chalk.red('Database error'));
  });
  mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
      console.log(chalk.green('Database connected');
    });
```

**Error**

[image]

**MongoDB version:**

- MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
- connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
- MongoDB server version: 3.4.9

Comment: Something might be an error in username or password

Comment: @kedarsedai Thanks for the comment,, But the same username and password working on mongo shell.

Comment: So are you trying to connect in `MongoDB Atlas`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add `{useNewUrlParser: true}` to your options. Plus can you post the error message so we can better understand the problem you encountered?

Update:

It seems like your user name or password is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have update the console error in the same question.

Comment: It seems like your user name or password is not correct.